# Setting environment variable when using Mex environment

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I am currently using a package called [Cuba](http://www.feynarts.de/cuba/), and I would like to use it within a Matlab mex environment. The problem is, how can I set the environment variable `CUBACORES` to disable the automatic parallelization?

This does not work with mex:

```
export CUBACORES=0
```

So, the question is, is it possible to specify environment variable at compile time or run time with Mex?

Answer (score 2):

Within MATLAB, set environment variables with the [`setenv`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/setenv.html) function.

```
setenv('CUBACORES', '0');
```

Naturally you'll need to do this before the library reads it.

If you are compiling a mex file that uses the Cuba library then you can set the environment variable from you mex file code. Exactly how to do that depends on which platform you target. Again, the environment variable must be set before the library reads it.

Comment: so it's not possible to do at run time through, for instance, preprocessor?

Comment: The preprocessor is part of compilation of the mex file. The env variable in question is read at runtime, in a different process. If you are compiling the Cuba library then you could patch their code to disable threading.